# I have individual scripts on my prefabs, all doing the same thing when I want them to reference different objects

Tags: visual-studio, gameobject

In my game I have a simple prefab of a cube. On this cube I have a  Script called "Lore". And a box collider 3x the size of the cube that I have made into a trigger and given the tag "Lore".
That is all.
Underneath my cube prefab (as a child) I have created a Canvas called "Message".
So every single Cube prefab has a collider, Lore script. and a Canvas called Message.

In my PlayerMovement script I have created an OnTriggerStay() so that when I walk into the "Lore" trigger it calls upon another function.  Like so:

```
private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other) 
{
if (other.tag == "Lore")
        {
            Debug.LogError("Inside Letter Box");
            FindObjectOfType<Lore>().ClickEToPickUpLetter();
        }
}
```

Therefore the entie time I am inside of the "Lore" Trigger it is recalling   FindObjectOfType().ClickEToPickUpLetter(); Over an Over.

The function it is calling looks like this.

```
 public GameObject loreMessage;


public void ClickEToPickUpLetter()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
        {
               loreMessage.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
```

In this case. While I am in the trigger, if The user Clicks "e" my GameObject loreMessage is being set to active.
In my inspector I referenced the CANVAS that I made as my loreMessage. So that every time the user clicks "e" my Message Canvas is being set to active.
here is my problem. When i walk into the trigger "Lore" I have a Debug.Log that says "Inside Letter Box" so i know that my trigger is working. I have also put a Debug.Log into my ClickEToPickUpLetter() Function. So i know that function is being called aswell when the user clicks "e". My problem is that the GameObject that is being turned on (In my case loreMessage, as in my Canvas) is the same canvas every single time.

I have this prefb placed over multiple parts of the map. And each object has a lore script with the same collider. The only difference is that on each object i have referenced a different canvas, so that when the user clicks "e" a new canvas opens up , dislaying a new image.
Why is the same canvas being referenced every time the script is called even though each individual script has reference to a different canvas/GameObject. is this because it is a prefab? All i am trying to accomplish is simply walking up to a trigger. In this case "Lore" being able to press "e" on top of it. And when the user presses the button a new canvas is being opened. every time they enter a new collider. But it doesnt seem to be opening the game object i have referenced in the inspector. Instead it opens the first canvas i originally created every time. Thanks any answers are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!!! My problem was that my script on my prefabs were not working because when I would call my script.

```
FindObjectOfType<Lore>().ClickEToPickUpLetter();
```

It was only calling the first instance that it found of this script.

Rather I needed to access the Script of the individual object. In this case  I did this,

```
if (other.tag == "Lore")
    {
        Debug.LogError("Inside Letter Box");
        //FindObjectOfType<Lore>().ClickEToPickUpLetter();
other.gameObject.GetComponent<Lore>().ClickEToPickUpLetter();
     }
```

}

This way instead of finding the first Lore script it could using FindObjectOfType. I am able to find the Lore script on the thing that I collided with by grabbing the script as a COMPONENT, like gameObject.GetComponent();

Ive learned that I can do this in any scenario as long as I call upon the object im accessing first. Just referencing it inside of the inspector isnt enough.